# WordPress site migration - icons missing

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have recently migrated my local site to a staging server by following the steps at https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress and everything seemed to have worked correctly.

Initially the database of each was pointing to the incorrect url's (wp_options siteurl and home fields) and needed switching, but having done this nearly everything has moved correctly - except for the icons.

The theme being used pulls it's icons from a number of different sites (font-awesome, ionicons etc.) but none of them are showing. Having looked in the  tags of each site I can see that they are pointing to the incorrect url (dev site to staging and vice versa).

Does anyone know where I would need to go to amend this? I have searched the database and cannot find from where this is being pulled.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this in the end.

1. Go into the admin panel into **Settings > General**
2. Change the **WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** to a different address (in this case I just added 'www.' to the current URL) and save the changes.
3. This redirected me and I had to sign in again with the username and password.
4. I then went back into the same area and returned it to it's original URL and saved the changes.

I believe this may have been an issue with the visual composer plugin needing to recompile the URLs. Either way, this resolved the issue.

Thanks for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 3):

you can either use a plugin for instance like this [https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-font-awesome/] .Just install the plugin and activate and all the icons will be added automatically.

Or alternatively you can do it manually of which I believe was the approach you used initially. All you have to do is add this single line of code in your theme’s header.php file just before the  tag.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

Though you can also load stylesheets or scripts in WordPress to properly enqueue them. For instance, instead of linking to the stylesheet from your theme’s header template, you can add the following code in your theme’s functions.php file.

```html
function wpb_load_fa() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'wpb-fa', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_load_fa' );
```

So in short, you can either check for the code on the **header.php** just before the  or **functions.php** under en-queued scripts.

Hope this helps Hellen.
Thank you

Comment: I resolved this before reading your answer so cannot say that this solved the problem. I have posted my solution below. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in case anyone else is struggling with this issue and missing WPBakery icons, the solution is easy:

1. Go to admin > WPBakery Page Builder > Design Options
2. Don't edit anything, just click 'Save Changes'

Your icons will then appear.

Reading the above comment about recompiling URLs, I remembered that the above process needs doing every time the WPBakery plugin is updated, which is what triggers the recompile.

Answer (score 0):

Hay I had the same problem. I added define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' ); in Config.php and changed the URL in Settings>General too ..
But when I saw icons disappeared from theme and the editor too. Then I Removed the lines of site url and home from Config.php and saved the icons appeared ..
If you WPBAKERY is not showing icons after migration check if you have done these edits in config.php comment them and check the website ..