# WordPress migration: Font awesome icons do not show work

Tags: migration, icons, font-awesome

I'm going to migrate the site http://www.thetrekkr.com (from a friend) to another server. The current server does have problems, until I migrate the domain I made a subdomain which is http://www.thetrekkr.pd-design.at. Everything works except the **themes (Avada) icons** - this must be font-awesome-icons. The icons are working in Edge but not in FF, Chrome, Opera.

I tried the following ways to fix the problems:

- Change the links in the database to the new subdomain (plugin better search replace)
- adding a .htaccess file to load the icons (https://theme-fusion.com/knowledgebase/are-your-font-awesome-icons-or-custom-fonts-not-showing-up/)
- adding the following code in the functions.php to load stylesheets or scripts ([WordPress site migration - icons missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268569/wordpress-site-migration-icons-missing))
- changing many times from www without www etc.
- deleting browser cache, trying on more devices

Unfortunately nothing helps.

### Update

I notice I am getting these errors in my network tab. Are they a problem?

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.thetrekkr.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/assets/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.woff. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.thetrekkr.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/assets/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.ttf. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: While we don't mind supplementary links to a problem in questions, questions must demonstrate the problem in a self-contained fashion. The reason for this is that questions must be useful even after you have solved the problem, so if the only way readers can see the problem is to visit a website you are shortly going to fix or delete, then the question is not on-topic. Would you show in your question (a) an image of what "not working" looks like, and (b) any relevant JS/network logs from affected browsers?

Comment: ^ I will leave the above comment here, as I think it is good advice generally for Stack Overflow, but I have edited the question to keep it on-topic.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the info, I'll do it like that in future. Regards

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem but the solution I found was simple in the end.

Go to theme options -> advanced -> dynamic css/js and then disable file caching, that worked for me. You can also reset the cache on this page.

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, This is How I fixed missing awesome fonts after migration

I migrated my client's website from MAMP to hostgator using all in one migration but after the migration, all of the avada awesome font wouldn't show (front end and back end) after hours of trying to fix I finally found a solution.

Within the wordpress theme dashboard navigated to > Theme options > Advanced > Theme features > FontAwesome then re-selected every font awesome option then hit save.

I could now select all the font again :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a hardwired domain in your temporary site. The errors are an attempt to load assets from one site into another, and unless the remote site permits that explicitly, the browser will disallow it for security reasons. As the error indicates, if you wanted this configuration long-term, you can get the remote to allow it using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

However, since this configuration is an accident of using two domains, it would be better to modify your site code to get these fonts to load from a relative path starting from `/`, rather than referencing the domain explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Avada > Options > Advanced > Theme Features and check if the Font Awesome v4 Compatibility option is turned On. If not, turn it on and click Save Changes. And If it's already on then turn it off and turn it on again then click save changes.

Answer (score 0):

Wow after watching many many "solutions" and none worked for me.

My solution ended up being to watch the console errors to see a font connection issue https: to http: went straight to WordPress settings, added the 's' to the WordPress & Site URLs. I normally do this, seems I missed it, and it caused all my icons not to load. Good stuff hope this works when all the other normal solutions didn't work.